# Connecting MongoDB with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb, ecmascript-6

I am working on a project and I'm trying to connect mongodb with an angular application.

Essentially I am getting the collection and running it through express to map it through an array, and then using that array to create a dynamic page. I've gotten it through each of the systems, but I can't figure out how to connect it to the array. Any help is appreciated.

Full code can be found on github [here](https://github.com/khalid-talakshi/inline).

**Client/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr"  ng-app="inlineClient">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>InLine Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">  
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="eventsController as eventsCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="event in eventsCtrl.venues">
        <h1>{{event.name}}</h1>
        <h2>{{event.time}}</h2>
        <p>{{event.description}}</p>
        <!--<event></event>-->
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Client/app.js**

```js
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('inlineClient', []);

  app.controller('eventsController', ['$http', function($http) {
    var venues = [];

    $http.get('/events').then(successCallback);
    function successCallback(response){
      console.log('Got events successfully');
      console.log(response);
      venues.push(response);
    }
    console.log(venues);

    // $http.get('/events').success(function(data) {
    //   console.log('Got events successfully');
    //   console.log(data);
    //   events.venues = data;
    // });

  }]);

  app.directive('events', function() {
    return {
      restirct: 'E',
      templateUrl: './event.html'
    };
  });

//   var venues = [
//     {
//     name: 'Breakfast',
//     time: '9:00 AM',
//     description: 'Come on down to enjoy some good eats!'
//     },
//     {
//       name: 'Lunch',
//       time: '12:00 PM',
//       description: 'Come on down to enjoy some good eats!'
//     },
//     {
//       name: 'Contest Programming',
//       time: '2:00 AM',
//       description: 'Compete in some algorithm programming for some sweet prizes'
//     },
// ];

})();
```

**Server/app.js**

```js
"use strict";

let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let mongoUtil = require('./mongoUtil');
mongoUtil.connect();

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + "/../client"));

app.get("/events", (request, response) => {
  let events = mongoUtil.events();
  events.find().toArray((err, docs) => {
    //console.log((docs));
    let eventArr = docs.map(obj => ({ name: obj.name, time: obj.time, description: obj.description }));
    console.log(eventArr);
    response.json(eventArr);
  });
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log("listening on 8000");
});
```

Comment: Is there anything in your Browsers Console?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ControllerAs` syntax so you have to refer to `this` variable of controller

Take **`var self = this;`** in controller

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module('inlineClient', []);

  app.controller('eventsController', ['$http', function($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.venues = [];

    $http.get('/events').then(function(response) {
      console.log('Got events successfully');
      console.log(response);
      self.venues.push(response);
      console.log(self.venues);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
       console.log(error);
     })

  }]);

  app.directive('events', function() {
    return {
      restirct: 'E',
      templateUrl: './event.html'
    };
  });


})();
```

Inside the response change,

**`self.venues.push(response);`**

Comment: @Khalid Talakshi, any issue you are facing?

Comment: haven’t tried it. I’ll get back to you in a few hours

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, perhaps its something with my html?

Comment: can you add the value of `console.log(response);`

Comment: can you add `{{eventsCtrl.venues | json }}` in html and check what  it is rendering?

Answer (score -1):

I think your code needs to have server side code. I didn't find any back end except server/app.js maybe you need to watch [ https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3vQyqzqjZ637sWpKvniMCxdqZhnMJC1d ] which covers all the detail needs to develop web in mean.

Comment: The OP does have a backend... Also hhile this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.